# Faster python code

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I have a dictionary with names as keys and a respective list of occurrence positions as values. 
I would like to merge the equivalent names. This names were not previously added to its true dictionary key because they are not well written (e.g. misspelling). 
So, Sorted_tuple is a sorted tuple extracted from Dict.items(), and sorted so that the first elements are the ones that contain the higher number of occurrences. 
I wrote the following code but is very slow. How can I make it faster?
Thanks

Note: The check_list is there so that when the first loop reach the ith Name that already had previously been compared, it will not calculate the distance function with the next following Names. Example: if is already found that the 10th Name is equivalent to the 1st, there no need to compare the 10th with 11,12, etc.

EDIT: toy example

EDIT2: j from i+1

```
Dict = {'Pedro':[1,3,4,7,8,10],'Ana':[2,6,9],'Pedros':[5]}
sorted_tuple = sorted(Dict.items(),key=lambda x:len(x[1]),reverse=True)

check_list = [0]*len(Sorted_tuple)
for i in range(len(Sorted_tuple)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(Sorted_tuple)):
        Name_i = Sorted_tuple[i][0]
        Name_j = Sorted_tuple[j][0]
        ID_list_j = Sorted_tuple[j][1]
        if check_list[i] == 0:
            if distance(Name_i,Name_j) < 5:
                Dict[Name_i]+=ID_list_j
                check_list[j] = 1
            else: continue
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: A toy example would help.

Comment: Should 'for j in range(1,len(Sorted_tuple)):' actually be 'for j in range(i+1,len(Sorted_tuple)):'? i.e. j goes from i+1 to the length. Also i should go from 0 to len(Sorted_tuple)-1.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  It is 'for j in range(i+1,len(Sorted_tuple))'

Comment: You can bisect the sorted list for an n log n runtime, your continues are also pointless

Comment: Not sure about this, but by leaving the merging until you have all the different names, you will have to perform O(n^2) comparisons. How about if you merge the names as you collect them? Assuming 25% of the names merge, the cost of doing those comparisons is O((0.75n)^2) - i.e. about twice as fast.

Comment: Actually why are you sorting on the length of the lists, why not one name?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I'm sorting on the length of the lists, so that first names with the higher occurrences come first. I assume that since these names have the higher number of occurrences, they will likely to be the correct ones. And therefore, the occurrences concatenation  will be added to their lists and not the ones that occurred only a few times. After this calculation I can use the check_list to delete from the Names that were misspelled.

Comment: @barny, not sure if I understood correctly. I think check_list plays the role of merging.

Comment: I meant, can you merge names as you collect them, i.e. before you get to this point where you have to compare each one with every other one. Also, your distance function presumably calculates the full distance between the two names for every comparison - if you pass to it the distance threshold you want, i.e. 5, perhaps distance(name1,name2,5) can abort calculating as soon as that threshold 5 is exceeded at which point there is no value in continuing to calculate the full distance.

Answer (score 0):

One optimization is to skip the whole inner loop if the flag has been set:

```
check_list = [0]*len(Sorted_tuple)
for i in range(len(Sorted_tuple)):
    if check_list[i] != 0:
       continue
    for j in range(i+1, len(Sorted_tuple)):
        Name_i = Sorted_tuple[i][0]
        Name_j = Sorted_tuple[j][0]
        ID_list_j = Sorted_tuple[j][1]
        if distance(Name_i, Name_j) < 5:
            Dict[Name_i] += ID_list_j
            check_list[j] = 1
```

as nothing is done for all `j` in this case.

edit:
After OP has clarified that the inner loop index starts at `i+1` setting the flag for element `j` is correct.

edit2:
The most expensive operation to be avoided as much as possible is the call to `distance()`. One idea for this is that if you are using the Levenshtein distance algorithm then this distance is at least as large as the difference of the lengths of the two words which are compared.
This leads to this code which incorporates some minor linguistic changes as well:

```
check_list = [0]*len(Sorted_tuple)
for i in range(len(Sorted_tuple) - 1):
    if check_list[i] == 0:
        Name_i = Sorted_tuple[i][0]
        len_i = len(Name_i)
        for j in range(i+1, len(Sorted_tuple)):
            Name_j, ID_list_j = Sorted_tuple[j]
            if abs(len_i - len(Name_j)) < 5:
                if distance(Name_i, Name_j) < 5:
                    Dict[Name_i] += ID_list_j
                    check_list[j] = 1
```

The loop boundary for the `i`-loop is shorter by one now, `i` invariant assignment is done outside of the inner loop, tuple assignment is used, and the minimum criterium for a Levenshtein algorithm is checked before calculating the distance.
All these minor changes do not change the O(n^2) behavior but the do change the scaling factor.